# Python requests "Content type application/octet-stream not supported"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have some request in Postman that works fine. It uses multipart/form-data and I have some problems with it when i try migrate request to Python. (Using import requests).

So, my problem is that Postman can set content-type for different types of body. Here's example: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iChLo.png)

But in python it doesn't work like this. I can set content-type for file (application/pdf), but not for payload(json). So i get the error from api "Content type application/octet-stream not supported".

Here's my code

```
import requests

url = "{host}:{port}/{end_point}"

payload = {'input': '{ "name": "-", "name2": "-", "name3": ["-", "-"]}'}

files = [('file', ('contractFile.pdf', open('contractFile.pdf', 'rb'), 'application/pdf'))]

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ---'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

So i have TWO bodies in one request:

Request Body:

file (file): The file containing the claim template. -> this should be application/pdf

input (text): Additional input data for the claim template. -> this should be application/json

Tried this, error "Content-type ' not supported"

```
data = MultipartEncoder(
fields={
    'input': ('{ some_json }', 'application/json'),

    'file': ('contractFile.pdf', open('contractFile.pdf', 'rb'), 'application/pdf')
})
```

I tried some different things:

1. Set 'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data;', 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary='***', and things like this. (Not together); It doesn't help.
2. Also I thought that changing "data" to "json" in request can help, but with it API can't see my key for JSON that is "input", mb doing something wrong with JSON but after like 30 tries i gave up.

There is example of expected request

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvwEtOpAEPX1EGWtN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json
 
{
    JSON_BODY
}
------WebKitFormBoundaryvwEtOpAEPX1EGWtN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="---"
Content-Type: application/pdf
 
 
------WebKitFormBoundaryvwEtOpAEPX1EGWtN--
```

Remark: my response should be .text, there is no problem with it. I'm expecting text/plain;charset=UTF-8, not PDF-file.